# Eclipse-like layout on Vaadin

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I'm looking to design a page with separate sections on Vaadin7.

Earlier, i was convinced that each section as a `Panel` would do-- see [Vaadin menu design - which component at the top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38002220/vaadin-menu-design-which-component-at-the-top) on this.

Now, i need each of these sections be minimized/maximized at user's will. So - when the user clicks the minimize icon, that section will disappear (be minimized) until its maximize button is pressed. 
The overall design will be much like Eclipse.

What's the best design for this?

I can use Vaadin `Window`-s for minimize/maximize. but then, how do i manage their automatic placement in the overall layout?
I want the sections be resizable with respect to one another, just as in `Panel`-s.

If i use `HorizantalSplitPanel/VerticalSplitPanel`-s, how do i manage minimize/maximize?

One thing i can think of is:

- split the overall layout into `Panel`-s so that each section will be a
  `Panel`,
- put a `Window` in each panel,
- when minimize is pressed, make
  that window-minimize event also trigger to minimize the `Panel` that
  `Window` is in shrink as well.

How to achieve this? Is there a better way?

TIA.

Comment: Perhaps the [SliderPanel](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/sliderpanel) may be of some use, although i think it's not exactly what you're hoping for.

Comment: @Morfic i'll check it out